# Return union type causing typescript not to compile

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which is returning union type:

```
   export const getCarMakes = (year: number): Promise<IMakes |IErrorResponse> => {
  return fetch(
    'url', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
  .then((res: Response) =>  res.json())
  .then((data: IMakes | IErrorResponse) => data)
  .catch((error: any) => {
    throw new Error(error);
  });
};
```

With interfaces:

```
interface IMakes {
  makes: string [];
}

interface IErrorResponse {
  code: number;
  msg: string;
}
```

At moment VS code is complaining that

```
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'IMakes | IErrorResponse'.
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'IMakes'.
```

I think I missing something as I can get 2 completely different responses from API which can be a valid one with an array of the item or error with messsage. How I can sort this issue

Comment: This works fine `export const getMakes = (year: number): Promise<IMakes | IErrorResponse> => Promise.resolve({
    code: 0,
    msg:""
})`, could you post more code ?

Comment: Could you show the implementation of your function?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this before, the way I've fixed it is by checking what the function is returning before returning anything.

For example, take this function

```
interface Foo {
    foo: string;
}

interface Bar {
    bar: boolean;
}

async function fooBar(): Promise<Foo | Bar> {
    try {
        const response = await asyncFn();

        return Promise.resolve({ foo: '' })
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject({ bar: false });
    }
}
```

This function can return either `Foo` or `Bar`, but since the return depends on what happens in the `try/catch`, TypeScript won't type check for both if one case passes but not the other.

So when doing:

```
fooBar()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

TypeScript won't throw a TypeError because the return of the function depends on logic that makes it possible for the function to return both values.

Here is an example implementation of what I mean [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20asyncFn()%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20n%20%3D%20Math.round(Math.random())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20n%20%3D%3D%3D%201%20%3F%20Promise.resolve()%20%3A%20Promise.reject()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20fooBar()%3A%20Promise%3CFoo%20%7C%20Bar%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20response%20%3D%20await%20asyncFn()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(%7B%20foo%3A%20''%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(err)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.reject(%7B%20bar%3A%20false%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AfooBar().then(console.log).catch(console.error)%3B). I'm almost 100% sure that TypeScript only complains about this if you  have the `strictFunctionTypes` options.

Hopefully this is clear enough.